# Android HttpGet deprecated how to login to aspx site with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

I have an app which makes a login to a aspx website. The app worked fine with HTTPGet. But if I try to login with HttpURLConnection, I cannot get it working.
What do I do wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
public String getViewState( String viewStateUrl) throws URISyntaxException,  IOException {
    try {

        // Enter URL address where your php file resides
        url = new URL("https://Login.aspx");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "exception";
    }
    try {
        // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
        conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");//whatever you want
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

        InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response += line;

        }

        Document doc;
        doc = Jsoup.parse(response);

        Element nameInput = doc.select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").first();
        String inputValue = nameInput.attr("value");
        Log.d("Viewstate", inputValue);



        // Append parameters to URL
        String username = "SPA";
        String password = "ABC123";
        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("__VIEWSTATE", inputValue)
                .appendQueryParameter("ctrlUserName", username)
                .appendQueryParameter("ctrlPassword", password)
                .appendQueryParameter("btnLogin", "Login");
        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        // Open connection for sending data
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(query);
        //writer.flush();
        //writer.close();


     // Read data sent from server
        InputStream inputStreamPost = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReaderPost = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStreamPost, "UTF-8"));
        String linePost = "";
        Log.d("BufferReader","URL: " + conn.getURL().toString());
        while ((linePost = bufferedReaderPost.readLine()) != null) {
            response += linePost;

        }
        os.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }
    return "Succes";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use HttpUrlConnection at all.  If you would like to get a Java object from your server response, use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).  If you just want the response string, use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) or [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).